# FFMPEG - Create a slideshow video from images in a directory, sorted alphabetically

Tags: ffmpeg

I see [this page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images) on how to do this with images numerically. But I have a directory of images that look like this for example:

```
ADAM SANDLER.jpg
JOHN DOE.jpg
SAM SMITH.jpg
```

I want to create a video slideshow from all of the images in this directory, sorted alphabetically.

Is there any way to do this?

**EDIT**

In the end, I'm trying to create a vertical video to post on Instagram. These photos are portraits so it will need to be a "vertical" video. It seems FFMPEG is having issues with this, at least playing the video in Quicktime doesn't seem to be working. It needs to be a 15 second video, and there are 25 images.

This is the command I'm running, and it's just appearing black when I open it in Quicktime. When I open in VLC it's playing but only shows the first couple frames.

`ffmpeg -r 1 -i img%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the concat demuxer.

First, prepare a text file containing the list of all images in the order you want. In Windows, from a command prompt, you can run this command, in the folder:

`dir *.jpg /b /on > list.txt`

Now prefix each line with `file '` and suffix with `'`, so that each line looks like

`file 'ADAM SANDLER.jpg'`

you may want to duplicate the last line due to a bug in the fps filter.

Now, if all your images are of the same size, run

```
ffmpeg -f concat -r 1/2 -i list.txt -crf 20 -vf fps=8,format=yuv420p video.mp4
```

If not, and assuming `1920x1080` as output video size, run

```
ffmpeg -f concat -r 1/2 -i list.txt -vf "scale=iw*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih):ih*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih), pad=1920:1080:(1920-iw*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2:(1080-ih*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2,fps=8,format=yuv420p" -crf 20 video.mp4
```

The `-r 1/2` is the input framerate and determines how long each images remains, in this case, 2 seconds. I've set the output framerate at `8` because some players may fail to play the output. CRF controls the quality. Lower values produce better result but larger files.

---

**For the edited Q**:

Use

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25/15 -i img%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -vf "scale=iw*min(1080/iw\,1080/ih):ih*min(1080/iw\,1080/ih), pad=1080:1080:(1080-iw*min(1080/iw\,1080/ih))/2:(1080-ih*min(1080/iw\,1080/ih))/2,fps=30000/1001,format=yuv420p" out.mp4
```

Comment: I've updated my question to be more specific on what I'm trying to do. I've got the files in alphanumeric order at this point.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an animated gif, using "convert" command from ImageMagick utilities:

```
convert -delay 500 -loop 0 *.jpg myimage.gif
```

This will concatenate jpg files, showing every one half a second each, in a permanent loop.